# Class active is not working when used with <a></a> tag

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I'd to ask why `class="active"` is not working when used as an attribute of an `a` tag, for example:

```
<a class="p-2 text-dark {{Request::is('/') ? "active" :""}}" href="/">Main Menu</a>
```

Comment: This seems to be more of a html/css question than php or laravel related, unless your "active" class simply isn't inserted. In order to get people with the right expertise to read this question, you might want to consider changing the tags.

Comment: Bad type of question, how can we know why it's not working... You probably don't have .active anywhere in your included css files or you didn't include css files that contain that class.

Comment: what do you see in browser inspector?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works,

```
Request::path() == '/' ? 'active' : ''
```

Comment: hi dude I have tried your code but no result I just wanted to ensure that if I go for example to home page which is '/' then in navbar home  should be highlighted. Usually active is used with li but can I use active with a tag

Comment: I need to review your CSS before answer this. Because maybe in your CSS, 'active' is only defined for used with <li> only?